# Landscape pages are turned into portrait pages only in my system

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I had a ms-word document where it consists of portrait pages and some landscape pages at section breaks. When I opened the document all are turned into the portrait pages and no able to see the landscape pages. I have opened the same document in others system and there I'm able to see the portrait and landscape pages. Is there any settings in the ms-word got changed? Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Are you in normal print view? Ribbon View, Print View (2nd button)

Comment: it is view->print layout. but i dont know how to check whether it is in ribbon view or in print view.

Comment: I think its correct. I have a dutch version of office so I had to attempt to translate.